# Overide ActiveRecord ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

in my Rails 4 app i would like to override Active Record to create records with ids that have 7 digits of random numbers. Such as 4526378 instead of 1. I found a way to do this but im not sure its the right way to go about doing this. In my models i have:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :add_id

  def add_id
    self.id ||= SecureRandom.random_number(9999999) if self.new_record?
  end
end
```

Is this an acceptable way to do this? Will there be any collisions and if so what would happen, would it try again to create a record with a new SecureRandom. Also is there any way i can setup and initializer.rb file in my config/initializers that automatically does this for every model? Thanks

Ok so I added an initializer called active_record.rb in my config/initializers directory. The code inside looks like:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :set_id

    def set_id
        self.id = SecureRandom.random_number(9999999)
    end
end
```

This code above actually works perfectly but now a collision is the issue. In this code can i perform a check to make sure its unique? If its not then generate a new one. I would also be into changing it to `SecureRandom.hex` in order to allow letters so a chance of a collision descreases.

Comment: I think you should rather add an "uuid" field

Comment: @user1737909 I though about doing that but im using devise and doorkeeper for authorizations and they depend on the :id column so i would need to go an subclass every one of their controllers and change the search from :id to :uuid right?

Comment: I don't know devise, sorry, but maybe their doc give a solution to override the index key

Comment: Have a look at [the birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem). Your probability of collision with 1000 records using a 7-digit id is around 5%, and is close to 99% with as few as 9000 records. You'll have to validate for the uniqueness of that field.

Comment: @ZachKemp i updated my question with some new code i am trying out. To prevent a collisions is there anyway i can make sure the id is unique using that initializer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would probably leave `id` alone, and add another field to hold the random ID. Then, before create, generate new random IDs until you hit a unique one.

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :random_id, uniqueness: true

  before_create :set_random_id

  def set_random_id
    loop do
      self.random_id = SecureRandom.random_number(9999999)
      break unless find_by_random_id(self.random_id)
    end
  end

end
```

Note that, the more records you have, the longer it will take to find a random ID that isn't taken. This is why you should probably use a larger random number than 9999999, like a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) where collisions are virtually impossible.

Comment: Thank you for this. Are there any downsides of just using the default auto_increment. I just feel that in my api giving out the primary key id to users who request it isn't that secure.

Comment: I think you'd want to add a unique constraint in the database (and handle the inevitable exceptions from the database) as well. Just validating uniqueness inside Rails is not sufficient.

Comment: @CristianRivera If that's your worry, just use auto-increment and add some real authentication. Choosing random IDs doesn't replace having actual authentication (see [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)) unless you're using *big* random URLs like UUIDs.

Comment: In my app im using devise and also doorkeeper for the oauth endpoint. That should be sufficient right or do i have the wrong idea?